# Regex to select every semicolon except the ones enclosed within Square brackets []

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a string based upon semicolon except the semicolons inside a square bracket!

```
string="'[Forsyth, Jennifer K.; Asarnow, Robert F.] Univ Calif Los Angeles, Dept Psychol, Los Angeles, CA 90095 USA; [Bachman, Peter] Univ Pittsburgh, Dept Psychiat, Pittsburgh, PA 15213 USA; [Mathalon, Daniel H.] Univ Calif San Francisco, Dept Psychiat, San Francisco, CA 94143 USA; [Mathalon, Daniel H.; Roach, Brian J.] San Francisco VA Med Ctr, San Francisco, CA 94121 USA; [Asarnow, Robert F.] Univ Calif Los Angeles, Dept Psychiat & Biobehav Sci, Los Angeles, CA 90095 USA'"
```

when I used

```
strung=filter(None, re.split("[;]", string))
```

the output was

```
["'[Forsyth, Jennifer K.",

 ' Asarnow, Robert F.] Univ Calif Los Angeles, Dept Psychol, Los Angeles, CA 90095 USA',

 ' [Bachman, Peter] Univ Pittsburgh, Dept Psychiat, Pittsburgh, PA 15213 USA',
```

---

This removed all the semicolon even within the square brackets. 
How do I maintain the square brackets and the semicolons within them and split on the base of all other semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead based regex for splitting:

```
strung = filter(None, re.split(r';(?![^\[\]]*\])', string))
```

`(?![^\[\]]*\])` is the negative lookahead to assert that `;` is not within `[...]`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP5hW2/1)

**Output"**

```
'[Forsyth, Jennifer K.; Asarnow, Robert F.] Univ Calif Los Angeles, Dept Psychol, Los Angeles, CA 90095 USA
[Bachman, Peter] Univ Pittsburgh, Dept Psychiat, Pittsburgh, PA 15213 USA
[Mathalon, Daniel H.] Univ Calif San Francisco, Dept Psychiat, San Francisco, CA 94143 USA
[Mathalon, Daniel H.; Roach, Brian J.] San Francisco VA Med Ctr, San Francisco, CA 94121 USA
[Asarnow, Robert F.] Univ Calif Los Angeles, Dept Psychiat & Biobehav Sci, Los Angeles, CA 90095 USA'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried escaping brackets but I was missing out!

Comment: @Thomas Christensen Yes I did wait those 10 minutes to accept the answer. Very elegant solution. I was on it for about an hour or so but couldn't get it right.

Comment: @vds5344 I didn't realize you had to wait. I just got excited :-)

Comment: Perks of being a new member. I just have so much to learn. *Overwhlemed*

Comment: However, this regex does not check if the semicolon is really inside the square brackets, it only matches them  before a closing square bracket without checking for the opening one.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets have a different meaning in regular expressions - usually they are used to match a single character of a list of characters.  Regardless, what you want is actually this:

```
\[;\]
```

This escapes the brackets in the regex.

Comment: OP is not really trying to split on literal `[;]`

Comment: ah, I see you properly addressed his *real* question :-)

Comment: My bad, I didn't phrase the question properly I guess. Thanks for the answer.